# how to remove null columns from spark df with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

i have a df with null values in every row,as

```
col1       col2      col3      col4  
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|null    | null    | foo     |  null       |
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|  null  | bar     |  null   |  null       |
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
| null   |  null   |  null   |     kid     |
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
| orange | null    | null    |  null       |
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
```

and i need to remove all null columns and the output df should be a single row ,as

```
 col1       col2      col3      col4  
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|orange  | bar     | foo     |     kid     |
|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
```

What should I do to achieve the desired result?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with my test dataframe:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |d   |
+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|cc  |null|
|null|null|null|dc  |
|null|bb  |null|null|
|aa  |null|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

and the test code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max

df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test.csv")

cols = [max(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
df.groupBy().agg(*cols).show(10, False)
```

gives the results:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |
+---+---+---+---+
|aa |bb |cc |dc |
+---+---+---+---+
```

where I have used the `groupBy` and `max` function.

Comment: thanks for your valuable time,actually my column values are strings ,if so how to take max col,is there any walk around way

Comment: The numbers are just an example, will work with strings too I think.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative-

```scala
df1.select(df1.columns.map(c => first(c, ignoreNulls = true).as(c)): _*)
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +------+----+----+----+
      * |col1  |col2|col3|col4|
      * +------+----+----+----+
      * |orange|bar |bar |kid |
      * +------+----+----+----+
      */
```